# How to model end of rope?

Tags: modeling

I've seen lots of tutorials on how to create a rope but I can't seem to find more than one where they address the end of a rope.

I'm trying to create something like this where it's starting to unravel in my model it should unravel after a knot, though

[image: end of rope unraveling]

Any ideas on how to do that?

I took a look at this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T__5FyCHL4E
But it seems to make the unraveling too drastic and stylized. Also, the rope in that tutorial is twisted differently from the picture above which is also how my model should look.

Comment: hello, you should tell how you've made your rope so far. Also, have you tried hair particles?

Comment: What I did was just a quick subdivision of the flat end and just extruded and stretched the ends. It was enough for a first render because I had other models I had to create for the scene but it does not look great, which is why I've been looking for a better way. I'll look into hair particles. Sounds like that could work. :)

Answer (score 1):

you may achieve it using curve hair from blender 3.3

Here is what I quickly made:
[image]
I order to have the same result you will have to use EEVEE as the render engine and set the curve shape to stip in the render properties. increasing the "additional subdivision" value will smooth the strips[image]

Here is the node set up. I colorize the importants node, the orange one is where you will choose which object the curve hairs base should be shrink wrapped to. Tweaking the value of the green node on the left will allows you to increase the distance between the fibers of the rope.
Tweaking the gradient on the green colorRamp node will allows you to choose precisely how close the fiber are (left of the ramp is the base of the fiber and right of the ramp is the tip of the fiber / white color means not close, black color means so close they touch each other)
[image]

Here is where I get the knowledge about the new 3.3 hair tool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF49gQcqIy4&ab_channel=THELUWIZART

Here is the official blender file to train with this new tool: https://studio.blender.org/films/heist/gallery/?asset=6072

Comment: Thanks! That's a very thorough answer. Very much appreciated! Do you know if there's a way to do this with Cycles? I'll look into hair particles as moonboots suggested. Shouldn't that achieve something similar, do you think?

Comment: Ah, the hair thing possible with 3.3 releases today. Nice coincidence. Watching that youtube video you linked to makes me think that should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jonas it would probably be possible to use cycles and hair particles, the advantage of the curve hair method is that you can comb them and have a good control with the geometry node over a bunch of parameters